# Handling of batch requests in SAPUI5 with sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel

Tags: odata, sapui5

If I change a property of an OData entity to an invalid value (SAPUI5 client) and send that value to SAP Gateway Server using `submitChanges` I got the following message in the log file:

> Service returned messages for entities that were not requested. This
>   might lead to wrong message processing and loss of messages

Now I would expect that the callback for "error" would be called but it is always "success".

Inside the callback for success I have a list of responses (in this case with an error).

Now I am asking me, why the error callback is not called?

I assume because the overall batch response is most of the time "OK" also if one request of the batch contains an error?

So do I have to implement error handling in the success callback? Or should the server send an overall error response?

I am using SAPUI5 1.28.15 (with 1.30.6 at least the cited message seems to be removed) and switched batch mode to "on" (if batch mode is off, callback will not be called!).

Comment: mhhh in my case I found that one of my properties (ENTITY) was not supplied with GET_ENTITY-method, means the method was empty, now after filling every entity's get_entity method it is working without this error.